# How do I format the headers field in step function API invoke

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I am trying to execute a AWS API via step function. I need to pass the `authorizationToken` value in the header field.

```json
{
  "ApiEndpoint": "xyz.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com",
  "Method": "POST",
  "Headers": {
    "authorizationToken.$": [
      "$.InputToken"
    ]
  },
  "Stage": "test",
  "Path": "/",
  "RequestBody": {
    "productType": [],
    "xxx.$": "$.xxx",
    "yyy.$": "$.yyy",
    "zzz.$": "$.zzz"
  },
  "AuthType": "IAM_ROLE"
}
```

I am getting the following error -

> The value for the field 'authorizationToken.$' must be a STRING that contains a JSONPath but was an ARRAY (at /States/GetDeclarations/Parameters)

This is the default syntax for the API invoke -

```json
"Headers": {
    "Header1": [
      "HeaderValue1"
    ],
    "Header2": [
      "HeaderValue2",
      "HeaderValue3"
    ]
  }
```

When I modify this to

```json
"Headers": {
    "authorizationToken": [
      "1234"
    ],
    "Header2": [
      "HeaderValue2",
      "HeaderValue3"
    ]
  }
```

It works fine.

I need to make the value of `authorizationToken` a variable that takes its value from the input.

My Input data looks like this

```json
{
  "xxx": "123",
  "yyy": "123",
  "zzz": "123",
  "InputToken": "123",
  "aaa": "123"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [States.Array](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html#asl-intrsc-func-arrays) Intrinsic Function as I've shown below. This allows you to inject an array into a node in your `Parameters` block. In this case, you just want a single item in the array, but you can include multiple items as well (e.g., `States.Array($.item1,$.item2,$.item3)`).

Check out the other [Intrinsic Functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html) as well, as they are handy for overcoming challenges like this.

```
{
  "ApiEndpoint": "ccqk9ijm0h.execute-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com",
  "Method": "POST",
  "Headers": {
    "authorizationToken.$": "States.Array($.InputToken)"
  },
  "Stage": "test",
  "Path": "/",
  "RequestBody": {
    "productType": [],
    "xxx.$": "$.xxx",
    "yyy.$": "$.yyy",
    "zzz.$": "$.zzz"
  },
  "AuthType": "IAM_ROLE"
}
```